# Is masturbation haram or not?

Tags: fiqh, masturbation

Aslamualaikom,

Is masturbation haram? I really don't know if it's haram or not. I've done a lot of research on it. Even the great scholar Xakir Naik said that it's not clear about masturbation in Islam. If I can't get married before age and I have strong sexual desire( common human thing) then I can only masturbate to prevent myself from acts such as zina.

If you have an answer, please let it be with some reference. 
Thank you!
May God bless us all, Amen!

Comment: Masturbation is addictive. If you get addicted, it will reduce your intentions for marriage. It's better leave it alone and don't think about it. There is no real way to stop it but only your desire to stop it.

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/masturbation-and-islam

Comment: Technically, this is a duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/is-masturbation-haram, but this is marked as a duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/masturbation-and-islam