# The issue of masturbation with me?

Tags: masturbation

Assalmu Alaykum,

I am actually 16 urs old and asking about masturbation and is it haram? I am also addicted to it and I want to stop but I can’t I would like some advice on this please.

Comment: I just wonder if we already have reached 100 questions asking whether masturbation is haram? Please check the site about similar questions, use relevant tags and if you don't find an answer ask!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is masturbation Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24521/is-masturbation-haram)

Comment: @Medi1Saif oh yes we most likely reached over 100. Every other day on this site I find a question about masturbation. We need like a new flag for like "search site" instead of like duplicate lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's haram to masturbate. it even says so in the Quran

The main interpretation comes from a Quran verse: “[The believers are] those who safeguard their chastity; except from their spouse or their dependents […]; But whoever seeks anything beyond that—these are the transgressors” (Surah 23, The Believers 5-7). The last ayah (verse) is the one including -in both Sunni and Shia Islam- the self-stimulation of the haram realm, because all form of sexual gratification, practiced outside of marriage, is relentlessly prohibited since infringes on the law of Allah.

try to stop and if you have the urge then read the Quran or do something else that doesn't make you want to do it.